# Any terms meaning the 'first snow of autumn'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I am wondering if there is a term for the 'first snow of autumn'. The word I am looking for could come from the semantic field of meteorology, or perhaps farming etc. I know of the terms 'killing frost' and 'cold snap' but these are not really right.

Comment: _Primautumnix_, derived from badly mangled Latin and not a real word. But I think it deserves to exist.

Comment: Inuktitut language has a word for this: **apigiannagaut** [*](http://www.aadnc-aandc.gc.ca/eng/1303138100962/1303138315347)

Comment: That is so awesome. I thought the concept must exist in other languages at least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only term I've heard that relates is *first frost*. Farmers and folks with gardens use [guides like this one from the Farmer's Almanac](http://www.almanac.com/content/us-frost-chart) to plan ahead for all the bulb and perennial planting they need to do before the first frost.